# To split http_referer url parameters and query string into a human readable data

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have my nginx logs in the following format

```
165.225.106.84 - - [20/Dec/2017:12:44:45 +0530] "POST /api/auction/auctionmaster/onauctionmasterfilter HTTP/1.1" 200 3227 "http://auction-dev.iquippo.com/viewauctions?type=upcoming" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36" "115.112.162.2" "{\x22auctionType\x22:\x22upcoming\x22,\x22addAuctionType\x22:true}"
```

I want to split my http_referer value like this

```
domain:- http://auction-dev.iquippo.com
param1 :- viewauctions
param2:- if any
query_param1:- upcoming
and so on..
```

I am trying this post on elastic search discussion forum:- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/extracting-domain-from-url/36219

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: There might be typos and you can't copy paste this directly, but it is a start of what you are trying to do.

Start by storing your referal in a variable and add a tag with add_tag, later do a if tag in tags.

```
grok {
    match => { "access_log_line" => "%{LINE_WITH_REFERAL}"}
    add_tag => [ "referal" ]
}

if "referal" in [tags] {
    grok {
        match => { "referal" => "%{POST0}" }
        add_tag => [ "referal_step2" ]
    }
}

if "referal" in [tags] {
    grok {
        match => [ "referal_uri" => "%{POST_COMP}" ]
    }
}
```

Example lines:

```
3227 "http://auction-dev.iquippo.com/viewauctions?type=upcoming"    
2522 "http://auction-dev.iquippo.com/viewauctions?foo?type=upcoming"    
327 "http://auction-dev.iquippo.com/viewauctions?foo?bar?type=upcoming"
```

First GROK pattern for the entire line:

```
POST0 %{INT} "http://%{IPORHOST}/%{WORD:uri}\?%{GREEDYDATA:data}
```

GrokPatterns that will match your params:

```
POST1 type=%{WORD:query_param}"
POST2 %{WORD:param1}?type=%{WORD:query_param}"
POST3 %{WORD:param1}?%{WORD:param2}?type=%{WORD:query_param}"
POST4 %{WORD:param2}?%{WORD:param2}?%{WORD:param3}?type=%{WORD:query_param}"

POST_COMP %{POST1}|%{POST2}|%{POST3}|%{POST4}
```